# How can i swipe the images in android

Tags: android, imageview, swipe

I was intended to download the images from a dynamic URL and show them  on the grid view. when the user click the images in the grid view it should be seen in full screen and also the user can have to swipe the images which are downloaded from the URL.?

Now i can able to show the images which are in SD card..!

I have googled but didn't got a clear idea about that..!

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : Use Gallery in order to display the image.

Step 2 : Use lazy loading to download the images from server and display inside Gallery.

Since Gallery is auto swiped so there is no need to right specific code for it. Ya you can use  onFling in order to control over swiping of Gallery.

Comment: Dear Lalit., Lemme try..! Can i have any samples for lazy loading..!